# How to create WCF Data Service on a base type

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, wcf-data-services, odata

I am trying to do something like this:

```
public class DataService : DataService<EmployeeCollection>
{
  public IQueryable<EmployeeBase> GetEmployeeData(string EmpIdSubstring)
  {
    var employees = new List<EmployeeBase>();
    employees.Add(new Level1Employee());
    employees.Add(new Level2Employee());
    return employees.AsQueryable();
  }
}
```

Here:

1. `Level1Employee` and `Level2Employee` classes are derived from `EmployeeBase` class.
2. `EmployeeBase` class definition is decorated with `[DataServiceKey("Id")]`.
3. `EmployeeCollection` contains an `IEnumerable<EmployeeBase>`.

But when I browse this service in the browser, I get the following error:

> Internal Server Error. The type 'Level1Employee' is not a complex type or an entity type.

I tried moving the `[DataServiceKey]` attribute from `EmployeeBase` class to `Level1Employee` and `Level2Employee` class definitions. But getting the same error.

Note that the service works fine if I returns an employees collection containing elements of type `EmployeeBase`.

Is it possible to achieve this? Any help/ pointers/ insights are much appreciated.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a shot in the dark based upon the behavior of DomainServices from RIA services.

Try adding a function for each subclass.  One each to return `IQueryable<Level1Employee>` and `IQueryable<Level2Employee>.`

Comment: this will not work for me, as a single collection of type  EmployeeCollection may contain elements of both Level1Employee and Level2Employee types.

Comment: Yeah, you don't actually have to use the functions.  I saw the "OData" tag, figured you were using the OData tools, and if they're anything like the RIA Services tools, having those functions available will allow the OData service to manifest the classes.  At this point, RIA Services wouldn't know they exist.

Answer (score 0):

The context class (EmployeeCollection in your case) must expose a public property with a getter and a type of IQueryable and the EmployeeBase class must have the DataServiceKey attribute in order for EmployeeBase (and all its derived types) to be recognizes as entity types.
You also need to add [WebGet] attribute on your method for it to be recognized as service operation.

Comment: Hi Vitek, 1. EmployeeCollection has a public getter property with return type as IQueryable<EmployeeBase>. 2. EmployeeBase class has a DataServiceKey attribute with "Id" as the key. 3. [WebGet] attribute is in place too. Still it is not working.

Comment: "Not working" means that you get the error described in your question? Is the Level1Employee a public class? If possible, can you post its definition? In any case if you could catch the exception in debugger and post the stack trace, that would help as well.